# In IntelliJ Idea 15 how do you enable live previews when using Find in Path?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

In IntelliJ Idea 15 when using `Find in Path`, if the `Preview` tab is selected results are not shown when searching.

Instead it says:

`Can not preview regular expression search yet`.

What is it waiting for? Does some form of indexing need to be initiated?

This behaviour is not found in IntelliJ Idea 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand it as "search preview for regular expressions is not supported in this version". With IntelliJ 2016, it definitely works even with regular expressions. Try to uncheck "Regular expression" (if your search is simple enough).

Comment: I have seen it work in 2016, does another setting need to be enabled for 2015?

Comment: Just try a "normal" search with unchecked "Regular expression"